# Storing and replacing values in array continuously

Tags: arrays, labview

I'm trying to read amplitude from a waveform and shine a green, yellow or red light depending on the amplitude of the signal. I'm fairly new to labVIEW and couldnt get my idea that wouldve worked with any other programming language I know to work. What I'm trying to do is take the value of the signal and for everytime it updates I'll store the value of the amplitude into an index of a large array. With each measurement being stored in the n+1 index of the array.

After a certain amount of data points I want to start over and replace values in the array (I use the formula node with the modulus for this). By keeping a finite amount of indexes to check for max value I restrict my amplitude check to a certain time period.

However my problem is that whenever I use the replace array subset to insert a new value into index n, all the other index points get erased. Rendering it pretty much useless. I was thinking its the Initialize array causing problems but I just cant seem to wrap my head around what to do here.

I tried creating just basic arrays in the front panel, but those either are control or indicator arrays and can't seem to be both written and read from, its either control (read but not write) or indicate(write but not read)?. Maybe its just not possible to do what I had in mind in an eloquent way in LabVIEW.  If its not possible to do this with arrays in LabVIEW I will look for a different way to do it.

I'm pretty sure I got most of the rest of the code down except for an unfinished part here and there. Its just my issue with the arrays not working as I want them too.

I expected the array to retain its previously inputted data for index n-1 when index n is inputted. And only to be replaced once the index has come back to that specific point.

Instead its like a new array is initialized every time a new index is input.

[image: picture of the code]

[download link for the VI](https://puu.sh/EBFfy/33f59d4109.vi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do:
Transport the content of the modified array into the next iteration of the WHILE loop.

What happens:
On each iteration, the content of the array is the same. It is the content of the initial array you created outside.

To solve this, right-click the orange square on the left border of the loop, and make it a "shift register". The symbol changes, and a similar symbol appears on the right border. Now, wire the modified array to the symbol on the right. What flows out into that symbol on the right, comes in from the left symbol on the next iteration.

**Edit:**

I have optimized your code a little. There is a modulo function, and an IF clause can handle ranges. `..3` means "values lower or equal 3". The next case is "Default", the next "7..". Unfortunately, this only works for integers. Otherwise, one would use nested IF clauses with the `<` comparator or similar.

[image]